# python bokeh colour palette legend

Tags: python, legend, bokeh, color-mapping

I am trying out the awesome [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) visualization library for Python. 
I have one question on it. I am making something like a contour plot using this [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html) as a reference.

It's working great but to complete this I would love to have the color map as a legend. Basically I want the reader of the graph to be able to understand what the colors mean. Is there a ways to do this?

Comment: Given that the [git issue #1441](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1441) for this has been pushed from milestone 0.8 to 0.8.1, and then to 0.8.2, just 12 days ago, I would go out on a limb and say you can't do this without some kind of hack.

Comment: Ok thanks. I can wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's now a `ColorBar` class for doing this.  See

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#color-bars

```
from bokeh.models import ColorBar, LogTicker

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, ticker=LogTicker(),
                 label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0,0))
plot.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
```